# Disable child theme css on certain pages

Tags: css, child-theme, wp-enqueue-style

I have activated child theme and would need to completely disable the child theme css on certain pages, leaving only the parent theme css.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two methods to accomplish what you what need to do.

**METHOD 1**

The first method is to create a separate stylesheet from your child's main style.css, and then move all your css into that stylesheets. For this example, lets call this stylesheet custom-style.css.

As said, copy all the css that will be specific to only certain pages to this new stylesheet.

You can now enqueue this new stylesheet using [`wp_enqueue_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) conditionally using the [`is_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) conditional tag, only for the pages that you need. So open up your child functions.php and add the following in there

```
function enqueue_my_style() {
  if( is_page( SEE CODEX FOR EXAMPLES)) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/custom-style.css' );
  }
 }
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_style' );
```

**METHOD 2**

Default `body_class()` makes a few css selector available by default to target specific pages using css. Here are these selectors

- .rtl {}
- .home {}
- .blog {}
- .archive {}
- .date {}
- .search {}
- .paged {}
- .attachment {}
- .error404 {}
- .single postid-(id) {}
- .attachmentid-(id) {}
- .attachment-(mime-type) {}
- .author {}
- .author-(user_nicename) {}
- .category {}
- .category-(slug) {}
- .tag {}
- .tag-(slug) {}
- .page-parent {}
- .page-child parent-pageid-(id) {}
- .page-template page-template-(template file name) {}
- .search-results {}
- .search-no-results {}
- .logged-in {}
- .paged-(page number) {}
- .single-paged-(page number) {}
- .page-paged-(page number) {}
- .category-paged-(page number) {}
- .tag-paged-(page number) {}
- .date-paged-(page number) {}
- .author-paged-(page number) {}
- .search-paged-(page number) {}

When applying styles to specific elements, you can use these selectors to target specific elements for specific pages only, for instance

```
.home H1 {}
```

will only target the H1 element on the homepage

Comment: Thansk, I went with the first option, works great.