# Is it possible to make invisible a div only on certain pages using CSS?

Tags: css

I have a `div` with a unique `id`, and I need to make this `div` invisible but only on certain pages.

Using only CSS is it possible a solution like this?

```
#my_div{
   display: inline-block;
}
#my_div .post5187{
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: Before downvoting and close voting, read my answer. This is Wordpress related although it is css. The solution involves css selectors that **only** exists in Wordpress and is only available through the `body_class` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target the specific pages with the build in [`body_class`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) selectors.

> Themes have a template tag for the body tag which will help theme authors to style more effectively with CSS. The Template Tag is called `body_class`. This function gives the bodyelement different classes and can be added, typically, in the header.php's HTML body tag.

Comment: I forgot I've done a similar post sometime last year. Check it out [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/145774/31545)

Comment: ok thanks, but why the downvote? Just to understand how to improve my question

Comment: I did not downvote the question, but I suspect that the user who did did so because it looks like a generic css question which is off topic here. Although it is generic css, it is still Wordpress specific as it involves css selectors that only exists in Wordpress

Comment: I just finished to read the codex article...so it's easy as `<body class="page page-id-2>` and from the stylesheet `.page-id-2 {
 /* styles for only page ID number 2 */
}` Thanks!

Comment: Great, glad you solved it. `body_class` is really really helpful in styling.